# Different prices depending on date

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to have different prices calculated depending on the date of submission of the Google Forms in Google Sheets?

If parents register for summer camp before the 31st of May they get an early bird discount, if not they pay full price. I have the prices being called from a separate sheet, and can manually change them after the date but if I do that all of the prices before the date will be effected as well.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet: goo.gl/V0JRTz The formula is in row GZ.

Here are a couple of screenshots as well:

[image: The Separate Sheet with the costs]

[image: The table looks like this]

[image]

Comment: What you want can be done with Apps Script code.

Comment: Might you have any details on Apps Script, I did a quick search and couldn't find anything relating to dates? Thanks!

Comment: To do this with Apps Script, there are multiple parts that need to work together.  Something needs to trigger the code to run, then the processing is done, then the value(s) are written to the spreadsheet.  Any date manipulation is done with JavaScript date methods.  [JavaScript Date Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)  If you are using a Google Form, I'd install an "On Submit Trigger" that runs when the Google Form is submitted.  An "On Submit Trigger" can be in either a Form or the Sheet. [Trggr](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)